# Cycle comments on field--comment.html.twig

Tags: theming, comments

I would like to add a div for every comment on my field--comment.html.twig

On the template I've a "comments" variable, but if I cycle in this way, I obtain error (Fatal error: "0" is an invalid render array key in /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php on line 97):

```
{% for comment in comments %}
      {{ comment }}
  {% endfor %}
```

I would like to add "odd/even" class to comments.

[EDIT]
If I use a cycle like this:

```
{% for key,value in comments %}
  {{ dump(key) }}
{% endfor %}
```

keys are: #sorted, #pre_render, 'pager', '106', '107' (where 106 and 107 are comment ids)

Comment: #pre_render is for cache performance, 106, 107, ...contain a minimal build of the comment and they are fully prepared for rendering only in case of a cache miss. If you don't care so much for performance you can try to render the single comments, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
   {% set pre_render = comments['#pre_render'] %}

   {% for key, item in comments if key|first != '#' %}
     {% if key != 'pager' %}
       {% set item = { '#pre_render': pre_render, 0: item } %}
       <div class="comment-{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) }}">{{ item }}</div>
     {% else %}
       <div class="comment-pager">{{ item }}</div>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This work for the cycle, but when it prints "item", it loose all "content" values (author, fields, etc). This "content" variable is in the comment.html.twig template

Comment: I think that the #pre_render value is mandatory to render the comment. Should I work on a preprocess function?

Comment: Yes, it seems like you need #pre_render. I think it should be possible in twig, see the edit.

Comment: yesss, it works, thanks a lot! The alternative could be to insert a views, but it's better in this way :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop and set the odd-even classes by using following code:

```
  {% for comment in comments %}
            {% set classes = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
            <div{{ comment.attributes.addClass('comment-', classes ) }} >{{ comment}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work: Fatal error: "0" is an invalid render array key in /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php on line 97

I think that "comment", in the for cycle, is not a render array..

Comment: Did u clear the cache ?? have a look at this link https://gist.github.com/NikLP/cb9adc963036d1ffd8896928de2b9b7a

Comment: Of course :) your code is not different than mine, the problem is that "comment" is not a render array